# what happens to iPad iOS 3.2 app not marked as tested for iOS 4 when 4.2 comes out?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store-connect

I have an app written for iOS 3.2, I did not mark it as tested for iOS 4 when I added it to the app store.  I have since tested it and it works just fine but I do not want to submit an update if I do not have to.  Will they clear out all apps or not make the available if they have not been tested for iOS 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nah, everything will be fine. All that particular checkbox does is give you a little tag by your version number that reads (iOS 4.0 Tested). See [Rush Hour](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rush-hour/id336542036?mt=8) for an example. If it's iPad only, and using 3.2, you don't need to check this option at all. If you've built using the new 4.2 settings, you would check this if, for example, you now supported fast app switching, and had tested to see if that worked.

So, that checkbox isn't tied to actual app functionality... it's just a flag. For functionality, what matters is the "Base SDK" setting in your XCode project. This defines the highest version number you support; the "iOS Deployment Target" defines the lowest.

Answer (score 0):

I think they stay in the App Store, but obviously won't be able to use features of the newer iOS versions. But to be approved again, you have to follow any new guidelines, etc.